# Reprojecting seams from one mesh to another

Tags: python, algorithm, 3d, blender

Hi I got two 3D meshes that contains verticies, edges and faces. One mesh is a simplified version of the other one. Some edges on simplified mesh are marked as seams and I want to reproject theese seams to the complex one. Do you have any ideas how to do this?

I want to implment this mechanism to increse my automatic UV unwrapper speed, because some large meshes are unmanagable.

Comment: Is this something you know how to do conceptually, but not in code? Then show the code you've attempted so far please. Or, is this a conceptual question, one that you're not sure how you'd even code? Then that's not a programming question, it's a math or algorithm question, which is not appropriate for StackOverflow. Code is the implementation detail of your design. If you don't have a design then you shouldn't be thinking about the programming yet.

Comment: It's a conceptual question. I've got some ideas, but when I think them over they fall apart. Oh I've seen a lot of algorithms questions, so I tought it's ok to ask here.

Comment: Okay, you might still get help here but if you don't, that could be why. Just a heads-up.